# Drush command can't find Drupal module function

Tags: 7, drush

I created sample command in Drush.

I put it to sites/all/drush.

I am on my site root and calling this command works ok. But when I try to call any Drupal function in drush_MY_COMMAND function I am getting:

> Error: Call to undefined function

Could someone give me any hint how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like your site is not being selected.  Try calling your command with your cwd in the same folder as your settings.php file (e.g. cd sites/default); that should work.  You may also create an alias for your site, and call your command from any directory via `drush @site mycommand`

Comment: I go to default directory and launch command: drush --include=../all/drush jbip-migrate and I am getting about not found of node_load() function still :/

Comment: Anyway great thanks for help I try to resolve this later by creating site alias

Comment: If you are still having trouble, you may also post an issue in the Drush queue at http://drupal.org/node/add/project-issue/drush. Please follow the instructions at the top (e.g. provide output of drush status and --debug output of your command).